# Not getting notification for VoIP Push while it sent from php script

Tags: swift, xcode, voip, pushkit

I've used tokbox for video calling, and implemented VoIP push notification by following steps from [here](https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification).

As the script run son the backend it shows that push has been sent successfully, but VoIP push didn't received at app side.

While application is receiving the APNs notifications successfully.

Can any one please suggest the solution for this?

Comment: If you are debugging your app then, make sure you are using Development Sandbox environment. If you are using the live environment then you will not receive a notification while debugging.

Comment: Yes, I'm working in production environment.

Comment: First setup Development environment for notification in apple developer accounts and then. download development certificate. Then you will be able to get the notification while debugging.

Comment: I don't want to debug them, I'm not receiving the voip push.

Comment: In this case, i will need to have a look in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, After googling and healthy searching finally I got the problem with solution.

Actually problem was, when be try to getting the VoIP notification then we also need to enable the push notification as well.

Second thing is, I was testing the VoIP notification with the APN tester which was not right. then I tried houston to send the VoIP notification. There is different approach to send the VoIP notifications.

**For houston these commands I've used:**

- Install houston:
  `$ (sudo) gem install houston`
- Send VoIP notification: `$ apn push "<token>" -c /path/to/apple_push_notification.pem -m "Hello from the command line! "`

Hope this will help someone else!!

Happy coding :)

Comment: Try this also. https://github.com/Hitman666/ios-voip-push